# Any way to automatically lock *Me* out from *My Own* iPhone for a specific amount of time?

Tags: iphone

I am looking for a way to kick me off of My iPhone periodically for set periods of time to avoid getting distracted. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

PS: Inspired by http://xkcd.com/862/

Comment: I didn't realize you were the asked when I rolled back your last edit. If you _really_ want the non-standard capitalization, I won't reverse that edit again. (but someone else might)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I guess you don't want to be distracted by yourself constantly touching you phone right? That's what I need too.

My way to do this is totally **not recommended**, but that's the only way I have in mind. Get a passcode, do like 11 false attempt, and you can lock yourself out for 15 minutes or more. It's something extremely stupid to do, and I don't recommend doing that or anything similar.

Just in case some emergency happened, and you need to contact someone. You picked up your phone, and, ya. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Set recurring alarms and then manually enable airplane mode or power it off as directed / previously agreed upon with yourself.

With the toolset that ships on iOS, it's easier to hack your perception of what you wish to achieve. The tools you need are there on the device, but it's not an automated tool to disable the device.

Of course, there is no built in disable mechanism or even a timer you can set to turn off the screen - just alerts that trigger at a time or when you activate a geofence.

If you jailbroke your phone, you could probably use cron to schedule a shutdown event if you didn't mind an unannounced shut down of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

there is no automated way to enable Airplane mode, so you will have to disable it via the settings menu of your iPhone. If you have a Jailbroken one, there are numerous Cydia extensions that you can download which will help you schedule activation / deactivation of airplane mode.

you could used the app *iSleepWell*. It'll enable airplane mode whenever your phone is placed facedown. Also, *LockScreenAirplaneMode* app will give you an icon on your lock screen which will allow you to do this as well. Both these can only be activated if Cydia is installed.