# (preferably) free app to lock iPhone for predetermined periods of time

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation

Reading here

https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

my understanding is that I can ask question about third-party Apple software, as long as I don't ask "which is your favourite app to do something". However, there is also a [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site on Stack Exchange so I'm a bit confused as to whether my question is on-topic or not...please migrate my question to Software Recommendations if it's off-topic here.

Concerning duplicates, I've searched the site and I found

[Any way to automatically lock *Me* out from *My Own* iPhone for a specific amount of time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73522/any-way-to-automatically-lock-me-out-from-my-own-iphone-for-a-specific-amoun)

The answers don't satisfy me, because I don't want to jailbreak my phone. I know for sure that today there are some paid apps which don't require jailbreaking and allow me to disable the Internet connection (both WiFi and cellular data, but not cellular voice) with a recurring schedule, for example from 9 PM to 8 AM. Are there also free apps?

Requirements:

- the app should "resist" attemps to force the block, but it's not necessary that it's 100% tampering-proof. Its main use will be preventing kids to access the Internet after a certain hour, it's not like it must resist hacker attacks :-)
- the schedule should be configurable
- it should be possible (but not easy) to overcome the block if needed. For example, one evening it may be necessary to use the cell phone after dinner. In that case, for example pressing a button and then waiting 15 minutes with the screen on should allow to stop the block.

If free apps don't exist or have glaring flaws, I will accept suggestions for paid apps, but I'd prefer free apps.

Comment: Can you give any examples of the paid apps you've seen which don't require jailbreaking?

Comment: @grgarside I haven't seen them directly, but I was told by an acquaintance which I trust very much when it comes to iPhones. This app should do the job: http://offtime.co/

Comment: That doesn't offer any of the necessary functionality on iOS, with the blocking features only available on Android, as expected. I would be amazed if there are any App Store apps which are able to provide this functionality since iOS is a restrictive platform which wouldn't give any app permission to prevent other apps from being opened. I've given an answer to this end

Comment: @grgarside thanks! I didn't know this. Reading the description, I had the impression that the app would allow blocking the iPhone. But now that I read the description again, it does look like the blocking feature is only available on Android. What a scam! The free Android version allows blocking (at least, according to the description) while the paid iOS version doesn't. Glad I didn't buy it and instead asked you guys! Sure,  it's not the developers' fault (if I understand correctly, it's due to differences in the two OS), but still, they shouldn't charge more for an app which does less.

Comment: Is there no reason you can't limit internet access at the router level?

Comment: @OzzieSpin I don't know how to do that. I mean, I could switch the WiFi off, but that would mean no Internet for the rest of the family.

Comment: Trying to do something that the phone can't do will be far harder than blocking internet access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no App Store apps which are able to prevent other apps from being opened. Apple does not provide such functionality to apps, so you will not be able to find an app which is able to do this.

Preventing apps from being used is something the OS can do for some native apps. See Settings → General → Restrictions for being able to set a passcode to prevent access to certain functionality on the device.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of it may be possible with a custom profile on a managed (!) device(iPhone)... but it requires a Mac with Apple configurator... to create these profiles and to set the iPhone as managed...

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but I may fix this later during the year :-)